# save multiple text line in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, line, android-edittext

I want to know how to save multiple lines of text in a SQLite field.

I create a `EditText`
I enter my Input with multiple lines of text

IE:

> My test with
>   Multiple Line
>   Of description

When I save the text in SQLite using something like below, it only retains the first line.

```
db.insertDescription(EditText.getText().toString());
```

Is it possible to save all of the text instead of just the first line?

Answer (score 2):

Parse out the new lines and replace it with something else, e.g. `$%&%$`, and put the new lines back in when you fetch from the database.

Comment: Is ok! I intercep the enter key and replace it with <br/>

Comment: If my answer worked for you then please mark it as accepted by clicked the tick mark button (just below the score on the left-hand side)